# Integrate D3 with tableau

Tags: d3.js, tableau-api

How to integrate d3.js visualization to tableau dashboard with the help of tableau extension. we tried creating TREX file, and upload into the tableau Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

There could be lots of problems within your code or your procedures. For example...have you started an HTTP server on your local machine?

I think that the best way to resolve your problem could be to look at [this repository](https://github.com/sarinac/tableau-extensions-demo), try using the two examples, and then personalize the code according to your purpose.